# How to update AWS step function input with url of current step function

Tags: aws-step-functions

I want to capture the url of the current step function and update this json input:

```json
    {
      "log_telemetry": {
        "eventType": "telemetry",
        "operation": "start",
        "data": {
          "correlation_id": "69974248-7673-42fb-8d1d-e4e2bd3e0946",
          "start_time": "01/05/2022, 16:00:31",
          "environment": "stg",
          "step_function_url": "i want to update this string with the url"
        }
      }
```

I'm going to derive the url string by concatenating `https://console.aws.amazon.com/states/home?region=us-east-1#/executions/details/` and `$$.Execution.Id`

I can get the execution id using a Pass step, eg

```json
{
  "States": {
    "Set Up Config": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "ResultPath": "$.log_telemetry.data.step_function_url",
      "InputPath": "$$.Execution.Id",
      "Next": "Log Telemetry Start"
    },
...
}
```

but I'm unclear how I can prefix with a string.  `States.Format` concatenates them if I use it within a Parameters field, but setting it as the Result in the Pass step it just treats it as a literal, eg

```json
{
  "States": {
    "Set Up Config": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "ResultPath": "$.log_telemetry.data.step_function_url",
      "Result": "States.Format('https://console.aws.amazon.com/states/home?region=us-east-1#/executions/details/{}', $$.Execution.Id)",
      "Next": "Log Telemetry Start"
    },
...
}
```

the "data" element in the json input can contain an arbitrary number of fields

thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can add `step_function_url` as a sibling of the original payload in a `Pass` Task. [Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html#input-output-parameters) adds the execution id to the input.  The input is passed as output by default, which is what we want.

State Definition:

```json
"PassTask": {
    "Type": "Pass",
    "Parameters": {
      "step_function_url.$": "States.Format('https://console.aws.amazon.com/states/home?region=us-east-1#/executions/details/{}', $$.Execution.Id)",
      "log_telemetry.$": "$.log_telemetry"
    },
    "Next": "MySuperNextTask"
  },
```

Step output with the url, using the OP input:

```json
{
  "step_function_url": "https://console.aws.amazon.com/states/home?region=us-east-1#/executions/details/arn:aws:states:us-east-1:xxxxxxx:execution:StateMachineXXXXX-twWleHeOy2pw:ebbf738e-a2df-c6a0-f626-xxxxxxxxxx",
  "log_telemetry": {
    "eventType": "telemetry",
    "operation": "start",
    "data": {
      "correlation_id": "69974248-7673-42fb-8d1d-e4e2bd3e0946",
      "start_time": "01/05/2022, 16:00:31",
      "environment": "stg"
    }
  }
}
```

##### Edit: Add the execution url without changing the input shape

Adding the execution url to the original payload's `data` map requires an additional step.  The problem is that `data` has arbitrary key-value pairs.  The States Language has no syntax to  *set the value of `data.step_function_url` to `x`, but pass data's other key-values unchanged*.  It cannot do the second part.

Easily solved: add a Lambda task after `Pass` that merges the url value into the original shape.

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => { 
    event.log_telemetry.data.step_function_url = event.step_function_url;
    return event.log_telemetry;
}
```

The output now has the same shape as the OP's input.

Comment: Thanks @fedonev but i need step_function_url to be nested as a child of data, not a sibling of the original payload.  i don't understand your statement "It can't be a child of data, because data has arbitrary key-value pairs".  data will have a varying number of fields, but will always contain step_function_url in the original input, and i want to update that value at runtime

Comment: Glad to help.  I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the updated answer, i hadn't seen that lambda syntax before so thats useful.  i actually ended up managing it with 2 pass tasks

Answer (score 2):

in case anyone else finds it useful, i ended up using 2 pass tasks to achieve this

```
  "States": {
    "Determine Url": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "value.$": "States.Format('${step_function_url_prefix}/{}', $$.Execution.Id)"
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.determine_url",
      "Next": "Update Url"
    },
    "Update Url": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "InputPath": "$.determine_url.value",
      "ResultPath": "$.log_telemetry.data.step_function_url",
      "Next": "Log Telemetry Start"
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

We in our team found another way to update a subproperty (a property inside another property that belongs to the root json object) with just one state. It is a little bit tricky to understand first but it works perfectly. We basically make use of States.JsonMerge to replace the subproperty value with the new one.

```
 "State1": {
  "Type": "Pass",
  "End": true,
  "Parameters": {
    "root_property.$": "States.JsonMerge($.root_property, States.StringToJson(States.Format('\\{\"subproperty\": {}\\}', new_value, false)"
  }
}
```

Alternatively, using two states:

```
  "State1": {
  "Type": "Pass",
  "Next": "State2",
  "Parameters": {
    "root_property.$": "$.root_property",
    "root_property_temp": {
      "subproperty.$": new_value"
    }
  }
},
"State2": {
  "Type": "Pass",
  "End": true,
  "Parameters": {
    "body.$": "States.JsonMerge($.root_property, $.root_property_temp, false)"
  }
```